# How to make a minecraft source file to hold files for both a windows and a mac version, both held on the same USB?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently made a "minecraft usb" that allows me to play minecraft on both a windows, and a mac machine (my main machine.) The root directory has two folders, "MC_MAC" and "MC_WIN". Everything works great, but I'm looking for a way to make the two installations use the same "saves" file, so that I don't have to keep copying and recopying worlds from the Mac "saves" to the "windows" saves.

I thought of using the "Alias" function on mac, but that probably wouldn't translate well onto a windows machine.

Thoughts?

(Bonus points for getting the one "source" file to sync with the saves file on my mac when I plug in the usb...)

[Edit]

So far, I've got answers about how to run minecraft completely off a USB. This isn't my problem, I've gotten the game to work fine on both mac and windows, running completely off my 16GB Flash-drive, and leaving no trace (so far as I can tell) on the host machine, be it windows or mac.

Seeing as the MC for mac is a .app and MC for windows is a .exe, I can't use one install on both computers. And seeing as I have two installs, with each one generating it's own set of files, I have two save folders.

What I need is some way to make both installs read from and write to just one save folder.

Comment: Minecraft is a jar file. It can be executed on any system, so as far as I know you shouldn't have to do anything special.

Comment: How are you making it keep the saves file on the USB drive in the first place?

Comment: How are you starting Minecraft and make it use the files on the USB?

Comment: @Saint I got the application itself working fine (albiet a bit slower on mac), what I'm asking about is the saves folder, sorry if that wasn't clear.

And you can make minecraft run off a usb on both mac and windows.  I found the mac method to be cleaner/simpler, than the windows as it doesn't require any third-party apps, just some copy/paste work and a quick edit of the .plist.

Comment: @AntoniDevlin - I'm saying you shouldn't need separate folders for mac/pc, so there should be only a single saves folder. This has been my experience on linux/pc, anyways. Perhaps it's different with a mac.

Comment: @spoonless - Does the mac .app still download the minecraft.jar file? What happens if you put the .app and the .exe in the same directory?

Comment: @SaintWacko - The Mac part looks identical to what I have locally on my machine. The way I installed it created a separate `Library -> Application Support -> minecraft` tree on the usb, to be used only with minecraft. Don't know about the windows bit as this is the first I've seen of it.
I think putting those two in the same directory might break either one or both installs (depending on where I move it) seeing as both have specific file systems and paths that they refer to (I'm assuming that's how it works for Windows.)

Comment: So the running it on the Mac puts the saves on the USB in `[USB]/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves`? Then all you're missing is to make your Windows copy keep its saves there too? That's doable. Can you tell us where Windows is saving the worlds right now? Is it on the USB, or on the Windows machine? Give us something we can work with! :)

Comment: This is a good question, but I think that doesn't fit our Q&A format. it's more like an off-topic. Anyone can confirm if am I right about this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have modified Minecraft so that it writes onto the USB drive, but not in the same place for each version. All you need is a symlink to make the Mac side do what you want.

First, delete the Mac side's `saves`, then in a shell, run the following (based on your comment mentioning the path for Mac; adjust the path to the Windows side as needed):

```
cd '/Volumes/myusb/Library/Application Support/Minecraft'
ln -s '../../../whatever-the-path-is-to-the-windows-side/saves' ./saves
```

If I haven't got the Mac-side path right, then make sure the count of `..`s is adjusted to match. To test your symlink, run `ls saves` and you should see your list of worlds.

Most applications, including Minecraft, will follow a symlink as if it is not there, so this should do the trick. (Note that when viewed by the Finder, a symlink appears identical to an alias, but an alias will *not* function as needed here. An alias is more like a Windows shortcut — it is not *automatically* traversed by file system calls.)